# Unable to Parse JSON With Codeable

Tags: json, swift, jsondecoder

I am trying to understand Apple's Codeable function to parse JSON. I am following a tutorial on youtube this is the code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    struct Forex: Decodable {
        let open: Int?
        let close: Int?
        let high: Int?
    }

    let jsonUrlString = "https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=FX_INTRADAY&from_symbol=EUR&to_symbol=USD&interval=5min&apikey=demo"

    let urlObj = URL(string: jsonUrlString)

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlObj!) {(data, response, error)} in

    do {
        let forex = try JSONDecoder().decode([Forex].self, from: data)

    } catch {


    }
```

When i try to build i am face with 6 different errors: 
[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/REfxu.png)

When i apply the suggested fix from XCode it doesn't resolve the issue and the video, the person is able to build with none of these errors.

Can anyone please advise where i have gone wrong or has apple changed how you parse json using codeable?

Comment: Remove the `}` between `error)` and `in`.

Comment: There is no array at all in the JSON. Related : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51863329/how-to-append-all-elements-from-an-element-of-json-dictionary-to-an-array-with-a/51864004#51864004

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your root is a dictionary with 2 keys according to your attempt you need `timeSeriesFX5Min` key

```
class VCName:UIViewController {
   override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad() 

    let jsonUrlString = "https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=FX_INTRADAY&from_symbol=EUR&to_symbol=USD&interval=5min&apikey=demo"

    let urlObj = URL(string: jsonUrlString)

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlObj!) {(data, response, error) in
     guard let data = data else { return }  
    do {
        let forex = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: data)
        print(forex.timeSeriesFX5Min)
    } catch {

        print(error)
    }

    }.resume()
  }
}       


struct Root: Codable { 
    let timeSeriesFX5Min: [String:Forex]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey { 
        case timeSeriesFX5Min = "Time Series FX (5min)"
    }
}


// MARK: - TimeSeriesFX5Min
struct Forex: Codable {
    let the1Open, the2High, the3Low, the4Close: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case the1Open = "1. open"
        case the2High = "2. high"
        case the3Low = "3. low"
        case the4Close = "4. close"
    }
}
```

Comment: Let me see if i got this correct : you  mapped the Time Series to the timeSeriesFX5Min as their was no keyword matching this in the code then did the same for the open,high,low,close.

I also realized that you removed the } brace at ' error) in'  which was causing the errors. 
And the  keyword Root is just the name of the struct or does this have a different purpose?